# Multiply defined symbols found Qt3D

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt3d, qt5.2

When trying to compile [this project](https://github.com/Cherum/oculusqt3d) under Win7 with Visual Studio 2010 and Qt5.2/Qt3D,
I'm getting the following error:

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\OculusQt3D\oculusqt3d\build\Debug\OculusQt3D.exe 1
error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall QArray<class QVector3D,8>::~QArray<class QVector3D,8>(void)" (??1?$QArray@VQVector3D@@$07@@QAE@XZ) already defined in mdstate.obj    C:\OculusQt3D\oculusqt3d\build\Qt53Dd.lib(Qt53Dd.dll)
error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall QArray<class QVector3D,8>::QArray<class QVector3D,8>(void)" (??0?$QArray@VQVector3D@@$07@@QAE@XZ) already defined in Qt53Dd.lib(Qt53Dd.dll)  C:\OculusQt3D\oculusqt3d\build\MULTIBILLBOARD_LIBRARY.lib(databundle.obj)
error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall QArray<class QVector3D,8>::size(void)const " (?size@?$QArray@VQVector3D@@$07@@QBEHXZ) already defined in mdstate.obj C:\OculusQt3D\oculusqt3d\build\Qt53Dd.lib(Qt53Dd.dll)
```

The mentioned files are [mdstate.h](https://github.com/Cherum/oculusqt3d/blob/master/src/mdstate.h) / [mdstate.cpp](https://github.com/Cherum/oculusqt3d/blob/master/src/mdstate.cpp) and [databundle.h](https://github.com/Cherum/multibillboard/blob/master/src/databundle.h) / [databundle.cpp](https://github.com/Cherum/multibillboard/blob/master/src/databundle.cpp) and [qarray.h](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt3d/source/4deeee34eb54bdd2db0813579046e449dededae4%3asrc/threed/arrays/qarray.h) / [qarray.cpp](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt3d/source/36a829ad6fb44fd01f490c35e011f6fd2470ffdd%3asrc/threed/arrays/qarray.cpp)

After googling, there are quite a few possibilities where this error could originate from, but I can't get my head around this case.

Usually this is caused by including a .cpp instead of a header, accidentally including a file multiple times, missing include guards and stuff like that, which is not the case here.

So, does someone know what's the problem here?

Comment: Can you reproduce it on a more recent Visual C++ version?  Those functions are templates, they're supposed to be marked `selectany` by the compiler so that multiple definitions don't cause link errors (the C++ Standard states that multiple definitions of template functions are allowed, if and only if all definitions are equivalent)

Comment: Yes, I generated the project for Visual Studio 2012 with CMake under Win7 and get the same error when I try to run it. (Plus a new error with libovrd.lib)

Comment: Can you show some dumpbin output from the files in question (just the lines related to these functions, and maybe any others from the same class that are acting differently)

Comment: Also, it looks like there may be DLL imports involved.  Check on any macros related to creation-vs-use of the Qt DLL, that might affect a later `dllimport` vs `dllexport` keyword.